# Error with sqlite3 when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, homebrew, sqlite3-ruby

So I was trying to run `bundle install` in my newly created Rails app when I got this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150114-6877-1x6zk4k.rb extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/mc/qsk02mn50x96msk9zjxgzbmh0000gn/T/bundler20150114-6877-jsv17e/sqlite3-1.3.10/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/mc/qsk02mn50x96msk9zjxgzbmh0000gn/T/bundler20150114-6877-jsv17e/sqlite3-1.3.10/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/sqlite3-1.3.10/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My current sqlite3 version:

```
3.8.7.4 2014-12-09 01:34:36 f66f7a17b78ba617acde90fc810107f34f1a1f2e
```

Ruby:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

Brew:

```
0.9.5
```

Further info:

```
$ which sqlite3
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3
$ whereis sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Does this have anything to do with the clashing of Ruby 2.0 and the default Ruby 1.8 that came with my OS X? I'm using OS X 10.10.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution: Simply (manually) uninstall any existing versions of sqlite3 in your computer. What I did was:

1. Run `which -a sqlite3` to find out the directories in which sqlite3 was installed (for me there were 4 versions O.o). Delete all those sqlite3 files (by rm)
2. Manually delete all the sqlite-related files in `/usr/local/lib`, `usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/include`
3. After all the deletion, run `bundle install` again in your app dir, and the required version of sqlite3 will automatically be installed.

   `$bundle install
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
   Resolving dependencies...
    // Using a bunch of gems
    Installing sqlite3 1.3.10
    Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
    Installing uglifier 2.7.0
    Installing web-console 2.0.0
    Your bundle is complete!
    Use 'bundle show [gemname]' to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

I hope this saves some of your time, if you encountered the same problem as I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

check where your sqlite is installed to and run the following command (i assume /opt/local here)

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/local
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: hi! I came across the same answer on another post, tried it out but it didn't work. For my case, I used 
`gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/`
The same error message was displayed

Comment: sorry to hear that. it worked for me. you sure you checked that your sqlite3 installation is inside /usr/local? also is the command 'gem install sqlite3 --' working?

Comment: I somehow got 4 different versions of sqlite3 installed on my computer. I think that was the source of confusion. So I uninstalled them all and let `bundle install` handle the sqlite3 installation and it worked fine. Thanks for your reply man!

Answer (score 0):

**Try installing those in your console :**

Install brew :

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)""

# Add Homebrews binary path to the front of the $PATH
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

brew install sqlite3
brew install libsqlite3-dev
bundle install
```

Please check [this](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/) link !

Comment: oops did not notice, you are asking of OS X !

Comment: Updated answer, please check.

Comment: It's not my question ;) I hope `joeleba` will see your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
`brew install libsqlite3-dev`:

`Error: No available formula for libsqlite3-dev 

Searching formulae...

Searching taps...
`
and   
`bundle install` still returns the same error :-<

Comment: brew list -1 | while read line; do brew unlink $line; brew link $line; done

Run this command befor the brew install sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding my own solution for people other to try in case the above did not work for them.

I had to brew uninstall sqlite3 then I had to remove the sqlite3s from the rails app directory.

using `sudo rm -fr {app_route}/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/`

then used `bundle install` to reinstall sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me within a `Dockerfile` context on debian flavour:

```
apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
gem install sqlite3    # or: `bundle install`
```

.. and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

When you try to create a new project, then the rails try to create by latest version of the rails. Therefor, bundle install raised some errors.

When you create a new project, you can specify the version of the rails, which you have installed to OS X like following.

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.x.x
```

After that, you can create new project like following.

```
$ rails _4.x.x_ new PROJECT_NAME
```